# I having difficulty making an instance object for a class I just made using Java

Tags: java, class, object, netbeans, instance

Here is the class I attempted to create:

```
package rectangle;

public class Rectangle
{
    private double length,width;

    public void setLength(double length)
    {
        length=this.length;
    }
    public void setWidth(double width)
    {
        width=this.width;
    } 
    public double getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }
    public double getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }
    public double area()
    {
        return length*width;
    }
}
```

I believe I have correctly made the class. I am just trying to create and use a class that can calculate the area for a rectangle.
I then attempt to actually create the instance object:

```
/*Testing out the rectangle class*/
package rectangleclasstest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RectangleClassTest 
{

    static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        Rectangle rec=new Rectangle();

        //get length
        System.out.println("Please enter the length");
        rec.setLength()=keyboard.nextInt();  
    }   
}
```

I keep getting an error when I am trying to create the object rec as an instance of the Rectangle class I just made. It almost as if the program cannot find the class I just made at all. Any feedback would help. Thanks

Comment: please post screenshot of your package view in your IDE and then we might be able to help you further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your both classes are in two different packages. so when you want to use `Rectangle` class in your `RectangleClassTest` you need to import it.

You just need to add import line at the top of `RectangleClassTest` class like below

```
import rectangle.Rectangle;
```

Or as an alternative you can also call the class name by explicitly declaring the package as well, which is as below

```
rectangle.Rectangle rec=new rectangle.Rectangle();
```

You also have a compiler error on  line below

```
rec.setLength()=keyboard.nextInt();
```

which should have been like below

```
rec.setLength(keyboard.nextInt());
```

**Update:**  apart from that in your `Rectangle` class your setter method should be doing `this.length = length` and not the other way round. below is the correct way

```
public void setLength(double length){
    this.length=length;
}
public void setWidth(double width){
    this.width=width;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that the classes are in *different packages*. To use the class `Rectangle` in the package `rectangleclasstest` you will have to import it:

```
package rectangleclasstest;

import java.util.Scanner;
import rectangle.Rectangle;

public class RectangleClassTest 
{ ... }
```

Also, when you do:

```
length=this.length;
```

you are only modifying the parameter `length`. I guess you want to modify the instance attribute:

```
this.length = length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the rectangle package or explicitly name Rectangle,

```
rectangle.Rectangle rec=new rectangle.Rectangle();
```

Also, there is a compiler error here,

```
rec.setLength()=keyboard.nextInt();
```

Should be

```
rec.setLength(keyboard.nextInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using different packages. You can create the RectangleClassTest inside your rectangle package or import the Rectangle package

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure all angles are covered can we also take a look at your imports to make sure the Rectangle class was properly imported.
The problem also seems to be on this statement:
    `rec.setLength()=keyboard.nextInt();`

Should this not be:
      `rec.setLength(keyboard.nextInt());`

 That would seem to make more sense to me. If this answer helps do not forget to give it a vote up or accept it as the answer